# Doubt about a proof on linear congruence equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I'm going to copy-paste a proposition and a proof from my textbook. 
**Proposition**
$ax \equiv_m b \land GCD(a,m)=1$ has solutions $\implies$ if $c$ is solution of the congruence $ax \equiv_m 1 \implies c*b $ is the solution of  $ax \equiv_m b$

**Proof** 
$ac \equiv_m 1 \iff ac - mh =1$ 
$\iff acb = mhb = b$ $\iff a(cb) - b  = m(hb)$
$\iff m|a(bc) - b$

Which is the definition of $a(bc) \equiv_m b$
$\square$

But to me it looks very confusing, looks like it proves the $\Leftarrow $ implication.
I'd have written the proposition in this way:
$ ax \equiv_m 1$ has solutions $\implies ax \equiv_m b$ has $c*b$ as solution $ \land GCD(a,m)=1$.

 Am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It looks like it proves $\iff$

Comment: $gcd(a,m)=1$ if and only if $ax\equiv_m 1$ has a solution. This may help.

Comment: @YuqiaoHuang You may input $\gcd$ as `$\gcd$`.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Oh right, thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys, but as far as I saw, the $\iff$ might be not true. Is there anybody able to prove that $a(bc) \equiv_m b \land GCD(a,m) = 1 \implies ac \equiv_m 1$? Thank you again

Comment: $m=2, a = 1, b = 2, c = 2$ should answer that question.

Comment: Find a better textbook - that excerpt is horrendous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One too many $\iff$.

$a(cb) - b = m(hb)$ implies $m \mid a(cb) - b$. But $m \mid a(cb) - b$ does not imply $a(cb) - b = m(hb)$. There is no guarantee that $\dfrac{a(cb) - b}m$ is divisible by $b$, since we do not know if $\gcd(m,b) = 1$.

What you actually have is
$$\begin{align}ac \equiv_m 1 &\iff ac - mh =1\\
&\iff acb = mhb = b\\
&\iff a(cb) - b  = m(hb)\\
&\color{red}\implies m\mid a(bc) - b\\
&\implies a(bc) \equiv_m b\end{align}$$

Or one can prove that in general $$u\equiv_m v \implies ut \equiv_m vt$$ which
gets you the same result much faster, and follows simply because if $m \mid (u-v)$, then $m \mid (u-v)t$.